# Should we break each smallest possible thing as a separate story?

Tags: user-stories, story-points, work-breakdown-structure

We have a requirement where we need to analyze all the analytics placed on our website. We have total 4 pages on our website where we need to do this.

The story is simple:
As a developer, I want to list down all the events being tracked in pageA, pageB, pageC, pageD.

We are maintaining same version of these pages on mobile and on the desktop.

How should we break the stories:

1. Smallest possible manner, keeping all things independent: There would be 8 stories in total i.e. list down all events being tracked in pageA on mobile (same for pageB, pageC, pageD) AND 4 similar stories for desktop.
2. Keeping them independent but not breaking them to smallest possible manner: In this approach, we can create two stories i.e. one for mobile and another for desktop.

Any views by experienced people?

Comment: Your "story" is what I would call a "as a horse I want to draw a wagon"-story. Hint: you don't. Really. This is not a user story, it's command&control with a different syntax.

Comment: If this is not a user story and team works on it, how would the efforts get counted?

Comment: Well, if it's supposed to be a user story, you first need to find the *user* that needs to be in the story. *Who* wants this done and why? Your *developers* don't. They'd live happily ever after if this *never* gets done.

Comment: Okay. Got it. We have new product manager who wants to know what all information is being tracked on certain pages. So user here is product manager

Comment: Then I guess *he* wants it. And he wants *all* of it, not parts trickling in. So it's one story and your developers  break this down into *Tasks* however they see fit.

Comment: Okay. Could you suggest any way to split this?

Comment: There is no correct way or best practice to split something into tasks. Give the story to your team and let them decide how they want to split it.

Comment: But how would they estimate it without splitting it? It's difficult to estimate a bigger thing. If you break it, this becomes relatively simple.

Comment: Ask them. I mean they *have* to estimate user stories. If they *need* to split it before estimating, then have *them* do so.

Comment: Yes. Did the same. Half the team says above mentioned approach 1, the other half says approach2. We get such conflicts often. How to resolve them?

Comment: You let the team decide. There is no silver bullet. A *team* means they have to find a solution on their own. It's **self-organized**. Or at least supposed to be.

Comment: Agreed.. I am also part of the team.. I think we should have some consistent approach for this.. We have given total 10 points to these stories by approach 1 and 5 points by approach 2. It's fine for sometime but we should fix this with time

Answer (score 2):

I've some considerations about this question.
I would try not to explicitly define in the Story the complete list of pages, one by one. Guess the pages are forty, instead of four.
So my approach would be something more generic

```
As a Sales,

I want to analyse the customer behaviour on the [X] pages

So that I can sell more ads to specific customers
```

Obviusoly this is just an example. It looks weird the use of *As a Developer*, I would suggest these links to read about it https://www.industriallogic.com/blog/as-a-developer-is-not-a-user-story/ and http://blog.crisp.se/2014/09/25/david-evans/as-a-i-want-so-that-considered-harmful

Then once the Story is written according to a Definition of Ready, and all acceptance criteria are defined, then Developers can write technical tasks. For sure I wouldn't adopt your solution 1, it is too redundant. I'm not sure if it is the case to split into two stories for Desktop and Mobile, those can be part of the acceptance criteria. I simply would create the Story simpler, then Developers can split up into Tasks, according to their best approach to the development of this story.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the story.

If it is < 2 h per page than you should be pragmatic and merge them based on different criteria.

If it is more than a day then separated stories makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You should split them into as small stories as possible ensuring that each story following **I N V E S T** strictly.

I recommend you this article if want to explore [INVEST](http://agileforall.com/new-to-agile-invest-in-good-user-stories/)